# Show / hide Adsense using display: none causing "No slot size for availableWidth=0" error

Tags: responsive-design, adsense

I'm using CSS media queries to show hide Adsense ads according to the screen size. This appears to work fine using the code below, BUT it is throwing this error:

*adsbygoogle.js:34 Uncaught TagError: adsbygoogle.push() error: No slot size for availableWidth=0*

```
<style>
.top-mob-ad { display: block; }
@media(min-width: 768px) { .top-mob-ad { display: none; } }
</style>
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- MyAd responsive -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle top-mob-ad"
 data-ad-client="ca-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXX"
 data-ad-slot="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
 data-ad-format="auto"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```

I understand that the error is caused by the ad's parent element not having a width, but isn't this always going to be a problem with setting display: none; ?

I could live with the JS errors, but I think this is impacting on my *active views viewable*, as this has dropped rather than gone up as I would have expected.

Any ideas how I can get this fixed?

If it makes any difference I'm using the Zurb Foundation CSS framework.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, I'm betting that they just expect us to live with the error.

That, personally, really bugs me as I like to see exactly zero errors in the console when I consider a site 'finished'.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change the below code

```
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```

to the $(document).ready(funct... as

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('ins').each(function(){
    (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
   });
});
</script>
```

Please load the blocks using Jquery at the end of the page load. 
I hope this help your problem.